# Def return in class as second, third argument for Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I am creating a class to make some calculations. The class would have 3 arguments to get started. I have done like this in a simplified representation:

```
class TheCalcs:

    def __init__(self, pk_from_db, cat_score_list, final_score):
        self.pk_from_db = pk_from_db
        self.cat_score_list = cat_score_list
        self.final_score = final_score

    def calculate_cat_score(self):
        #Do some calcs with the data of the pk_from_db and return that!
        a_list_of_scores = []  # create a list of scores 
        return a_list_of_scores

    def final_score(self): # The argument for this function would be the return of the calculate_cat_score function! 
        # Again do some calcs and return the final score 
        the_final_score = int()
        return the_final_score

    def score_grade(self): # the argument this this function again the return but now from the final_score function
        # Do some cals and return the grade
        the_grade = ("a string", "an integer")
        return the_grade
```

When I call the class I would have to present the arguments --> However as you can see I just do now the value of the first argument. The second and the third being calculated throughout the class. When I call the class just with one argument I will of course have an error of failing arguments. Anyone has an idea on that?

Comment: Why require those arguments to be passed in at all then?

Comment: If you don't know the value of those attributes at initialization time, why do you want to supply those attributes at initialization time?

Comment: What about making them optional or just initialize ``self.cat_score_list = None``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those values are calculated, simply don't make them arguments. You could instead call those calculation methods to compute the values:

```
class TheCalcs:
    def __init__(self, pk_from_db):
        self.pk_from_db = pk_from_db
        self.cat_score_list = self.calculate_cat_score()
        self.final_score = self.calculate_final_score()

    # ...
```

or postpone calculations until you need them.

Comment: Like this I am calling the second and third function in the __init__ function correct? This is also a lack of programming experience. I am going to have to see how this "works" but for now It seems great help!

Comment: @GuidoPeters: exactly. There is no rule that values for attributes set in `__init__` must come from arguments. You can set any attributes you like, and the values for those can come from any expression, including method calls on the new instance just created.

Comment: I had to play around a bit to get it going! But long live python console! I am all good to go!